# how can i find the unknown vertices of different degrees?

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph of order 25and size 62,degree of every vertex is 3,4,5 or 6.There are 2 vertices of degree 4, 11 vertices of degree 6.How many vertices of degree 5?

Comment: Assume there are $x$ vertices of degree $3$, $2$ vertices of degree $4$, $y$ vertices of degree $5$, and $11$ vertices of degree $6$ in a graph. What is the order of the graph? And what is the size of the graph?

Comment: yes i have tried this method and i solved problem.thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) says that
$$
\sum\limits_{v \in V} \operatorname{deg}(v) = 2 |E|
$$
where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ the set of edges. You are given that $|V| = 25$ and $|E| = 62$. Substituting, you have that
$$
\sum\limits_{v \in V} \operatorname{deg}(v) = 124
$$

As you know that there are $2$ vertices of degree $4$ and $11$ vertices of degree $6$, the remaining $12$ vertices must have their degrees sum up to $50$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: please read again my question and answer it.

Comment: @wajeehasundas: If you followed the logic in my answer, you should have been able to figure it out. There are $7$ vertices of degree $5$ (and $5$ vertices of degree $3$).

Comment: thanx this is correct answer but how we solve it mathematically?

Comment: i used hand shake theorm for another question but i cant solve that....

Comment: @wajeehasundas: Again, following the logic in my answer, you end up with the equation $3 a + 5 b = 50$, where $a, b$ are integers with $a + b = 12$ and denote the numbers of vertices of degree $3$ and $5$ respectively. A solution to this equation is $a = 5$ and $b = 7$.

Comment: thanx a lot this is helpful

Comment: how you have devided the size of graph? which is 3a+5b=50 and a+b=12...how can i devide size 27 and order 12?